# Formula Array - IFERROR ISBLANK IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data-table with 3 columns, Name-ID, Name and Total

In the data-set sometimes the Name-ID doesn't exist, so i want it to then look for Name. I believe at the moment my formula only looks for Name if NameID is blank.

Ideally i want to do:

IF NAMEID IS BLANK OR NAMEID ISERROR, look for NAME, if no match enter 0.00

This is what i have so far.........help?

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(P2),(MAX(IF(NAME = Q2, TOTAL))),(MAX(IF(NAMEID = P2, TOTAL)))), "0.00")
```

Comment: What's the "look for NAME" formula? Generally, you could do something like `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(P2),NAMEID=""),[look for name and return 0.00 if no match]))`.

Comment: I have to return MAX total for name or nameID

Comment: Sample data and desired result will be helpful.